# How to verify whether the abnormal integral is convergent or divergent?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, convergence

How to [verify the convergence](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3787948/740776) and divergence of the abnormal integrals $\int_{0}^{1} \frac{\sqrt[m]{\ln ^{2}(1-x)}}{\sqrt[n]{x}} d x$:

```
Integrate[Power[Log[1 - x]^2, (m)^-1]/Power[x, (n)^-1], {x, 0, 1}, 
 Assumptions -> Element[m | n, PositiveIntegers]]
```

No results can be obtained by running the above code. I don’t expect to get the integral value of this integral related to `m`, `n`. I just want to judge whether it converges (and the relationship between convergence and `m`, `n`). What should I do?

Comment: `tab = Table[{m, n, NIntegrate[Power[Log[1 - x]^2, (m)^-1]/Power[x, (n)^-1], {x, 0, 1}, WorkingPrecision -> 20]}, {m, 1, 10}, {n, 1, 10}] // Flatten[#, 1] &` doesn't indicate any convergence problem.

Answer (score 5):

The result of

```
Series[Power[Log[1 - x]^2, (m)^-1]/Power[x, (n)^-1], {x, 0, 2}]
```

$$ \left(x^2\right)^{1/m} x^{-1/n} \left(1+\frac{x}{m}+\frac{(5 m+6) x^2}{12 m^2}+O\left(x^3\right)\right)$$
implies the convergence condition `-1/n + 2/m > -1` at the origin and the result of

```
Series[Power[Log[1 - x]^2, (m)^-1]/Power[x, (n)^-1], {x, 1, 2}, Assumptions -> x < 1]
```

$$(-\log (1-x))^{2/m}\left(1-\frac{x-1}{n}+\frac{(n+1) (x-1)^2}{2 n^2}+O\left((x-1)^3\right)\right. $$ means that the integral converges at $x=1$ for any positive $m$.

Comment: Thank you very much, but I hope you can explain in detail why it converges at x = 0 and x = 1. After all, the sum of infinite convergent series does not necessarily converge.